# Java: Two inputs have same initial character

Tags: java

I have a problem where one of the toppings for the pizza `"mozarella"` also has the same initial character as `"m"` for medium.
How can I make it so that if the user enters `"m"` after the first character, it recognises `"m"` as mozarella and not medium again.

Currently, if I entered `mm`it would print `Your order is: Medium pizza with, Medium pizza with, £8.0`, but I want it to print `Your order is: Medium pizza with,mozarella,£5.0`.

```
    public class pizza {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        pizzaServiceA();
    }
    public static void pizzaServiceA(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double total = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter order:");
        String order = input.next();
        String pizza = "Your order is: ";

        if (order.equals("quit")){
            System.out.println("Program exiting.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        boolean size = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < order.length(); x++){
        if (order.charAt(0) == 'm' || order.charAt(0) == 'l'){
            if (order.charAt(x) == 'm'){
                total +=4.00;
                pizza += "Medium pizza with,";
                size = true;
            }
            else if (order.charAt(x) == 'l'){
                total +=5.00;
                pizza +="Large pizza with,";
            }
            else if (order.charAt(x) == 'h'){
                pizza +="ham,";
                if (size) total += 1.40; 
                else total +=2.10;
            }
            else if (order.charAt(x)== 'o'){
                pizza +="olives,";
                if(size) total +=0.80;
                else total +=1.20;
            }
            else if (order.charAt(x)=='p'){
                pizza+="pineapple,";
                if(size) total +=1.00;
                else total+=1.50;
            }
            else if (order.charAt(x)=='s'){
                pizza+="spinach,";
                if(size) total +=0.80;
                else total+=1.20;
            }
            else if (order.charAt(x)=='m'){
                pizza +="mozarella,";
                if(size) total =(long) + 1.00;
                else total+=1.50;
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Your first character must be m(medium) or l(large)");
        }
      }
        System.out.println(pizza +"£" + String.format("%.2f", total ));
    }
}
```

If I need to use a different method for this program, could someone explain what I need to use and how to use it? I am a beginner in java, so I'm still learning, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a check to see if `pizza` already has `Medium` in the string or something like that.

Comment: You can separate your `if` nesting. So that you handle the first char as the size, and letters afterwards as toppings.

Comment: @EricRobinson how do I do that? because the way im doing it right now is with the boolean size and if its true it adds to the total for a medium and if not true it adds for large.

Comment: You could parse whole words in a particular order, so you'd use "medium", not "M", as the input and insist that "medium" precede the toppings, or follow a key, as in `"size": "medium"`. You could have `{"crust": "thin", "size": "medium", "toppings": { ["mozzarella", "extra"], "pepperoni"} }`. You could use prompts to distinguish: `Size? "medium"\nToppings? "extra mozzarella, pepperoni"\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, an easy change is to change the code for medium from m to md. But you could check if the size has added (so the user has already added m or l) and if that is true then the other m will be the mozzarella. You can do that by adding in your code a counter in order to count if you have read the first character, so if the

`counter>0`

the m will be mozzarella.
Something like this should be ok

```
public class pizza {
public static void main(String[] args){
    pizzaServiceA();
}
public static void pizzaServiceA(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double total = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter order:");
    String order = input.next();
    String pizza = "Your order is: ";

    if (order.equals("quit")){
        System.out.println("Program exiting.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int count=0;
    boolean size = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < order.length(); x++){
    if (order.charAt(0) == 'm' || order.charAt(0) == 'l'){
        if (order.charAt(x) == 'm' && count ==0){
            total +=4.00;
            pizza += "Medium pizza with,";
            size = true;
        }
        else if (order.charAt(x) == 'm' && count > 0){
            pizza +="mozarella,";
            if(size) total =(long) + 1.00;
            else total+=1.50;
        }
        else if (order.charAt(x) == 'l'){
            total +=5.00;
            pizza +="Large pizza with,";
        }
        else if (order.charAt(x) == 'h'){
            pizza +="ham,";
            if (size) total += 1.40; 
            else total +=2.10;
        }
        else if (order.charAt(x)== 'o'){
            pizza +="olives,";
            if(size) total +=0.80;
            else total +=1.20;
        }
        else if (order.charAt(x)=='p'){
            pizza+="pineapple,";
            if(size) total +=1.00;
            else total+=1.50;
        }
        else if (order.charAt(x)=='s'){
            pizza+="spinach,";
            if(size) total +=0.80;
            else total+=1.20;
        }

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Your first character must be m(medium) or l(large)");
    }
    count++;
}
    System.out.println(pizza +"£" + String.format("%.2f", total ));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try case sensitivity. It might be annoying to remember whether mozzarella is "m" or "M" (that's only if you choose to maybe change `medium` to "m" and `mozzarella` to "M" and vice versa), but maybe you can change it to "mzz". Same principle applies to `"medium"` as well; maybe change it to something like "md", as @geo suggested.

Comment: yeah I did think of that, but the task says for medium to specifically be "m" and mozarella also has to be "m"

Comment: yeah but as I said, the task specifically says I have to use m for both